# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'long' with other issue?

Tags: c#, string, long-integer

I have a little problem which I have no clue how to solve. I will give the who;e code from the class so you can see what its doing:

{

```
class CompetitorDataFile
{
    //collection of DataFileRecords - people
    public List<DataFileRecord> DataFileRecords;
    public string FileName = "";

    //called when DataFile created
    public CompetitorDataFile(string FileName)
    {
        //creates the collection
        DataFileRecords = new List<DataFileRecord>();
        this.FileName = FileName;
    }

    //fill DataFileRecords with stuff from text file
    public void ReadDataFile()
    {
        foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines(FileName))
        {
            if (s == "") continue;
            DataFileRecord dfr = new DataFileRecord();
            dfr.Name = s.Split(',')[0];
            dfr.CPSA = s.Split(',')[1];
            dfr.PostCode = s.Split(',')[2];
            dfr.Rank = s.Split(',')[3];
            dfr.Score1 = s.Split(',')[4]; //new for score system
            dfr.Score2 = s.Split(',')[5]; //new for score system 
            dfr.Score3 = s.Split(',')[6]; //new for score system 
            dfr.Score4 = s.Split(',')[7]; //new for score system 
            dfr.Score5 = s.Split(',')[8]; //new for score system 
            dfr.Score6 = s.Split(',')[9]; //new for score system 
            dfr.Score7 = s.Split(',')[10]; //new for score system 
            dfr.Score8 = s.Split(',')[11]; //new for score system
            dfr.TotalSingleScore = s.Split(',')[12]; //new for score system
            DataFileRecords.Add(dfr);
        }
    }

    public int FindByCPSA(string CPSA)
    {
        //set index to 0
        int index = 0;
        //go through each record looking for CPSA number match
        foreach (DataFileRecord dfr in DataFileRecords)
        {
            if (dfr.CPSA.ToLower() == CPSA.ToLower())
            {
                //if it's found return the current index
                return index;
            }
            //increase index and move to next record
            index++;
        }
        //not found returning -1
        return -1;
    }

    //save DataFile records to text file
    public void SaveDataFile()
    {
        //delete backup file if found
        if (File.Exists(FileName+".bck")) 
            File.Delete(FileName+".bck");
        //make backup of existing
        if (File.Exists(FileName))
            File.Move(FileName, FileName + ".bck");
        //create a temporary array of string
        List<string> stringy = new List<string>(DataFileRecords.Count);
        //go through each DataFile record and create a single string line
        foreach (DataFileRecord dfr in DataFileRecords)
            stringy.Add(dfr.SingleString);
        //saves all strings to file
        File.WriteAllLines(FileName, stringy.ToArray());
    }
}

//a single record - one person
public class DataFileRecord
{
    public string Name;
    public string CPSA;
    public string PostCode;
    public string Rank;
    public string Score1; //new for score system
    public string Score2; //new for score system
    public string Score3; //new for score system
    public string Score4; //new for score system
    public string Score5; //new for score system
    public string Score6; //new for score system
    public string Score7; //new for score system
    public string Score8; //new for score system
    public Int64 TotalSingleScore; // used to get total score for one user

    public string SingleString
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10},{11}", Name, CPSA, PostCode, Rank, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5, Score6, Score7, Score8); //,{4} and , Score are new for score system
        }
    }

    public string PoshSingleString
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0,-20}|{1,-10}|{2,-9}|{3,-9}|{4,2}|{5,2}|{6,2}|{7,2}|{8,2}|{9,2}|{10,2}|{11,2}", Name, CPSA, PostCode, Rank, Score1, Score2, Score3, Score4, Score5, Score6, Score7, Score8);
            //return SingleString.Replace(",0", ""); //may be used to replace 0
            //return SingleString.Replace(",", ", ");
        }
```

I have a problem with this line of code

```
dfr.TotalSingleScore = s.Split(',')[12];
```

TotalSingleScore is the only int (all others are strings) as a result I get this error:
"Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'long'"

How do I go about solving this? **Code is C# and software is VS 2008 Pro**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since TotalSingleScore is declared as Int64, you have to use Int64.Parse.

Sample: `dfr.TotalSingleScore = Int64.Parse(s.Split(',')[12]);`

Answer (score 11):

use `long.Parse` or `long.TryParse`.

Comment: This would yield a different result whether ran on a 32-bit and 64-bit machine. He is explicitly using a Int64 in which Int64.parse return a long. int.Parse() != long.Parse()

Comment: @Andrew, you're wrong. `int` is 32-bit whether you are on a 32-bit or 64-bit machine, so the results will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

`dfr.TotalSingleScore = Int64.Parse(s.Split(',')[12]);`

`Int64.TryParse()`

Answer (score 0):

Take your string and convert it.  Like others stated the TryParse or Parse methods work great if the data might not be the casting type.  But you can also do it this way using System.Convert.

```
dfr.TotalSingleScore = Convert.ToInt64(s.Split(',')[12]);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint64.aspx

Comment: Convert.ToInt64(string) internally calls Int64.Parse(string). However, if you use Int64.Parse (or the equivalent int.Parse), you can specify globalization and formatting used when parsing.

Comment: True however Int64.Parse only takes a string and Convert.ToInt64 wraps Type.Parse to accept other types.  But I prefer Parse or TryParse moreso, just mentioning the other way.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, why are you splitting the string everytime? Wouldn't it be better if you just split it once and reuse the array?

```cs
        var myArray = s.split(',');
        dfr.Name = myArray[0];
        dfr.CPSA = myArray[1];
        dfr.PostCode = myArray[2];
        dfr.Rank = myArray[3];
        dfr.Score1 = myArray[4]; //new for score system
        dfr.Score2 = myArray[5]; //new for score system 
        dfr.Score3 = myArray[6]; //new for score system 
        dfr.Score4 = myArray[7]; //new for score system 
        dfr.Score5 = myArray[8]; //new for score system 
        dfr.Score6 = myArray[9]; //new for score system 
        dfr.Score7 = myArray[10]; //new for score system 
        dfr.Score8 = myArray[11]; //new for score system
        :
        etc
```

Not an answer for your question, but I thought I had to suggest this.